# how do i save state when open lik in new tap with react router dom

Tags: reactjs

I have a question how do I save the value when I open a new page, who has an idea

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/uppsala/category/', state: { the: 'query' } }} >
```

open lik in new tap

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation you can access the state passed through a link thanks to the `useLocation` hook:

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location

```
  let { state } = useLocation();
  console.log(state.the)
```

Comment: if i open new in tab the value state undefined

Comment: you can't pass data when you open in a new tab because you're generating a new router in the app that you're loading again. If you need to pass data use queryString for example